# How to select last 5 matches per team in soccer db in SQLite3?

Tags: database, sqlite, limit-per-group

I would like to extract some stats from a soccer DB. In particular, I would like to extract the last 5 matches per team. Is that possible with SQLite3?

I'm already able to do that on all records with the following query (not too fancy, but it works!):

`SELECT home_stats.team_name,
       home_matches,
       home_won,
       home_drawn,
       home_lost,
       away_matches,
       away_won,
       away_drawn,
       away_lost
FROM
       (SELECT soccer."date" AS "date", home_team AS team_name,
              COUNT(*) as home_matches,
              COUNT(CASE WHEN(SUBSTR(FTR,0,INSTR(FTR,":")) > SUBSTR(FTR,INSTR(FTR,":") + 1, LENGTH(FTR) - INSTR(FTR, ":") + 1)) THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) AS home_won,
              COUNT(CASE WHEN(SUBSTR(FTR,0,INSTR(FTR,":")) = SUBSTR(FTR,INSTR(FTR,":") + 1, LENGTH(FTR) - INSTR(FTR, ":") + 1)) THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) AS home_drawn,
              COUNT(CASE WHEN(SUBSTR(FTR,0,INSTR(FTR,":")) < SUBSTR(FTR,INSTR(FTR,":") + 1, LENGTH(FTR) - INSTR(FTR, ":") + 1)) THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) AS home_lost
              FROM soccer
              WHERE(soccer.FTR NOT NULL)
              GROUP BY soccer.home_team) AS home_stats
JOIN
       (SELECT soccer."date" AS "date", soccer.away_team AS team_name,
              COUNT(*) as away_matches,
              COUNT(CASE WHEN(SUBSTR(soccer.FTR,0,INSTR(soccer.FTR,":")) < SUBSTR(soccer.FTR,INSTR(soccer.FTR,":") + 1, LENGTH(soccer.FTR) - INSTR(soccer.FTR,":") + 1)) THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) AS away_won,
              COUNT(CASE WHEN(SUBSTR(soccer.FTR,0,INSTR(soccer.FTR,":")) = SUBSTR(soccer.FTR,INSTR(soccer.FTR,":") + 1, LENGTH(soccer.FTR) - INSTR(soccer.FTR,":") + 1)) THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) AS away_drawn,
              COUNT(CASE WHEN(SUBSTR(soccer.FTR,0,INSTR(soccer.FTR,":")) > SUBSTR(soccer.FTR,INSTR(soccer.FTR,":") + 1, LENGTH(soccer.FTR) - INSTR(soccer.FTR,":") + 1)) THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) AS away_lost
              FROM soccer
              WHERE(soccer.FTR NOT NULL)
              GROUP BY soccer.away_team) AS away_stats
ON (home_stats.team_name = away_stats.team_name);`

Comment: Maybe you just need to add the date in your select fields then add ORDER BY date DESC LIMIT 5 to your sub queries  (I don't use SQLITE, so I offer MYSQL syntax - pls use the SQLITE equivalent )

Comment: Tank you for your suggestion. Unfortunately, LIMITing any of the SELECt will simply return the first N rows only, while i'm asking for the last N match PER TEAM (i saw something similar involving row_number() and PARTITION for SQL SERVER, i think).

Comment: Can you use a separate query for each team using LIMIT and ORDER, then use UNION to aggregate them into one result? Or is the number or teams variable?